# Nodemon and ts-node stop working when used inside Docker using Docker compose

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, nodemon, ts-node

I have a basic Node app (Fastify API) that runs perfectly fine using ts-node and Nodemon when run locally. I am using ESM and not CommonJS, so I initially ran into an issue, but adding the `--esm` flag to the dev script fixed that. However, once I try to use Docker and Docker Compose I get this error:

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container api-ts-1  Created                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
Attaching to api-ts-1
api-ts-1  | [nodemon] 3.0.1
api-ts-1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
api-ts-1  | [nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/*
api-ts-1  | [nodemon] watching extensions: ts
api-ts-1  | [nodemon] starting `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229  -r ts-node/register ./src/app.ts`
api-ts-1  | Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/da3015c1-4b7b-48e5-b603-30f55b36fe5e
api-ts-1  | For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
api-ts-1  | TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /app/src/app.ts
api-ts-1  |     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
api-ts-1  |     at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:99:9)
api-ts-1  |     at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:142:36)
api-ts-1  |     at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:91:20)
api-ts-1  |     at DefaultModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:263:26)
api-ts-1  |     at DefaultModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:179:22)
api-ts-1  |     at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:63:26)
api-ts-1  |     at DefaultModuleLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:203:17)
api-ts-1  |     at DefaultModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:156:34)
api-ts-1  |     at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:141:17) {
api-ts-1  |   code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
api-ts-1  | }
api-ts-1  | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Aborting on container exit...
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container api-ts-1  Stopped                                                                                                                                                         0.1s
canceled
```

This is the same error I got when running outside Docker before adding the `--esm` flag. I have tried adding the flag to my set-up, but it still fails. Here is my set-up:

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --esm src/app.ts"
  },
  "author": "ClimateClever Pty Ltd",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <filename>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fastify/mongodb": "^7.0.0",
    "fastify": "^4.20.0",
    "fastify-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

Docker:

```
# with only prod dependencies and no code yet
FROM node:20-slim as base
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci && npm cache clean --force
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# a dev and build-only stage. we don't need to copy in code since we bind-mount it
FROM base as dev
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN npm install
CMD ["/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon"]

FROM dev as build
COPY . .
RUN tsc
# you would also run your tests here

# this only has minimal deps and files
FROM base as prod
COPY --from=build /app/dist/ .
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Docker Compose:

```
# version: '2.4'
# versions no longer needed in docker compose as of 2020
# all features are included from 2.x and 3.x versions

services:
  ts:
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "9229:9229"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

I also added this file for the Docker Compose set up nodemon.json:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229  -r ts-node/register ./src/app.ts"
}
```

In case it helps here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Node 20",
  "_version": "20.1.0",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2022"],
    "module": "Node16",
    "target": "es2022",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node16",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need Docker here?  Can you use a host-based Node environment for local development, and Docker for integration testing and deployment?

Comment: No, we can do dev locally without Docker. However, there are a few reasons to be able to want to do it, and it should work.